# Connector fails when the object it is attached to moves

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape 0.93 is not yet available on MacOS so I am using 0.92.

I created the connector shown in the image "before", #1.

[image: looks ok]

Then with the selection tool grabbed the oval and moved it to the right, as shown in  image #2, "problem". As you can see the end of the connector connected to the oval now extends over the oval to the center.

[image: problem]

This does not happen every single time, but it happens very frequently.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're probably using 0.92.2 instead of the current 0.92.3. This looks like a bug to me. Bug reports for Inkscape should be made to https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape. Please search before posting a new one.

Comment: Thanks @Moini. 0.92.3 is not available yet for Mac.

I will report this as a bug.